# If $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}g(x) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}f(x)=1 $, Then$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} $ does not exist.

Tags: limits, functions

If $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}g(x) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}f(x)=1 $,

Then$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} $ does not exist.

iS this statement true.

I believe this is not true.

The main question I have is : If the limit is infinity, do say that the limit exists ?

Comment: That depends on the conventions used in your book/course. If it allows infinite limits (I usually don't) the answer is sometimes yes, example $1/(x-1)^2$, sometimes no (example $1/x-1$).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the limit doesn't exist. We cannot say that it converges $\infty$. It is okay to say that as $x\to 1$, $|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}| \to \infty.$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, it is! Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: We have to exclude the case $g(x)\equiv 0$ in a neighbourhood of $x=1.$

Answer (score 1):

Normally we do not, though some books and instructors do say that such limits exist.

However, this case is especially bad: depending on how $g(x)$ approaches $0$, the fraction $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ may diverge to $+\infty$, diverge to $-\infty$, or diverge by taking both positive and negative values of arbitrarily large magnitude. There’s no way to tell from the given information which of these is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information, this is an example when $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}g(x) = 0$, but $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} $ does not exist (even in $\infty$ sense) .

$g(x)=(x-1)\text{sgn} \sin(\frac{1}{x-1})$